# Paging a HTML page using C#

Tags: c#, html, paging

Can anyone give me some idea abt how to page a HTML page? The HTML page contains texts, video & pics. Tags include P, STRONG, BR, I, Table, UL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try look here:

http://www.aspxtutorial.com/post/2011/02/02/How-Paging-Works-in-the-DetailsView-Control.aspx

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/paging-data-results-t3333991.html

Hope this helps.